# Highcharts Histogram show percentage on Y Axis

Tags: highcharts

Given the HighCharts example of a histogram here:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram

I am looking to make data in the histogram blue columns/bins and the Y axis show as a percentage of the overall dataset rather than the actual values. Example 4 Columns might show 25% / 50% / 10% / 15%

I cannot find an example of this so I am assuming it will require some data manipulation?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qvu7shLg/15/ ?

Comment: Thanks @ewolden this is exactly what I was looking for!